# Android development bluetooth chat example not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to loadup the android bluetooth chat example using eclipse:

I haven't tampered with any of the code but straight away I get 23 java errors, can anyone help?

Thanks.

Here is what i get...

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

The import android.view.Window is never used    BluetoothChat.java  /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 33 Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 481    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 488    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 489    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 480    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 460    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 459    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 438    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 437    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 413    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 412    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 393    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 392    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 388    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 371    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 370    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 339    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 338    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 323    Java Problem
The field PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated    AccelerometerPlayActivity.java  /AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay    line 75 Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 322    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 302    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 303    Java Problem
No exception of type IOException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 283    Java Problem
The method e(String, String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, IOException)   BluetoothChatService.java   /BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat    line 284    Java Problem
```

Comment: Post relevant source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run bluetooth program on emulator.
Run your program on android device